# filling in input fields with splinter

Tags: python, html, forms, testing, splinter

I am trying to fill in fields on a login form with splinter.  When I examine the rendered page, I see that the username input box has both a tag and a name of "u".  How can I fill in this field from splinter?  I tried the following:

```
from splinter import Browser

url = "http://www.weiyun.com/disk/login.html"
browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit(url)
browser.fill("u", "foo@bar.com")
print "done"
```

But there is no such field according to the error returned:

```
ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "u"
```

How does one fill in the input fields on pages like this using splinter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your form is inside an `iframe`, use [`get_iframe()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/iframes-and-alerts.html#using-iframes) to interact with it:

```
with browser.get_iframe('_qq_login_frame') as iframe:
    iframe.fill("u", "foo@bar.com")
```

Demo to show the difference:

```
>>> browser = Browser('firefox')
>>> browser.visit(url)
>>> browser.find_by_name('u')
[]
>>> with browser.get_iframe('_qq_login_frame') as iframe:
...     iframe.find_by_name('u')
... 
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.firefox.WebDriverElement object at 0x102465590>]
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much!  I haven't worked much with html before except for scraping simple pages - the whole iframe stuff is new to me and I'm reading up on it now.

Comment: I see how I can view the iframes with web developer in firefox.

Knowing that I needed to interact with an iframe is the key piece of information I was missing.  Is web developer in firefox the best way to figure out the structure of the page or are there better ones that you experienced guys use?

Comment: @user3677370 browser developer tools are must have and use, definitely. Glad it is solved.

Comment: After filling in the username and password, I succeeded in pushing the login button, but for some reason, I needed to push it twice in my code.  I wonder why it was necessary to push twice before login would happen?  Is there more than one way to push the button?  
  
    iframe.find_by_id("login_button").first.click()  
    iframe.find_by_id("login_button").first.click()